# How can I launch a python script in the Qt Console with a windows shortcut?

Tags: python, windows, ipython, shortcut-file, qtconsole

I have written a python program designed to run in the IPython qt console with inline graphs. My end users are factory workers running windows and are not technically sophisticated. I am trying hard to reduce complexity for them.

How can I create a shortcut in windows that launches my program for them in the qt console?

**Idea 1**

Ask the users to open IPython qt console with the desktop icon then enter:

```
%run G:\my_app\start.ipy
```

My `start.ipy` file consists of 2 lines:

```
%matplotlib inline
%run G:\my_app\my_app.py
```

The `start.ipy` file exists to reduce the number of commands they need to enter from two to one. This system works but I want to avoid it because it requires the users to remember and enter a command correctly.

**Idea 2**

Create a `start.bat` file with the flowing code:

```
ipython qtconsole --matplotlib inline -m my_app
```

Then put a shortcut to the .bat script on the desktop. This has two issues:

- The print statements in my_app don't work
- The black CMD.exe box pops up as well as the qt console

Ideally I would like a way to run an arbitrary .ipy file in qt console using a shortcut.

Comment: You can probably set matplotlib inline more easily using a [config file](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/config/intro.html). It can either be in the standard config location in `~/.ipython`, or in the working directory where the Qt console gets started. To avoid the command prompt window, you can start it using `pythonw -m IPython.qt`. I'm not sure how to launch it so it immediately runs a script, though.

Comment: Thanks, I used a config file to inline graphs for a few months. In the end I rewrote the whole program with PyQt5 to give it a more conventional GUI with embedded graphs. This solved the shortcut issue as a side effect.